# Radio button hotkey

Tags: c#, radio-button, hotkeys

I'm trying to assign a hotkey to a radio button so that it will check or uncheck depending on its previous state.

This is what i originally tried but didn't work.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)        
        {
            radiobutton1.PerformClick(); 
        }
```

Comment: What about: `radiobutton1.Checked = !radiobutton1.Checked;`

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Enter as a Hot-Key? Really? Note that you may need to move the focus off the rb..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot un-check a radio button by clicking on it. You need to deselect it programatically. Try the following:-

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
     radioButton1.Checked = !radioButton1.Checked;
}
```

Comment: I saw your comment and tried this, still does not seem to even check the radio button for me :(

Comment: Try setting `KeyPreview` property of the winform to `true`

Comment: and which event are you using - `key down`? Is the event firing?

Comment: I'm using keydown yes, it seems to work for normal buttons.